# Integrating Relay with Redux in React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, relayjs, graphql-js, redux-framework

I am new to react-native.My application currently uses **redux,[react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux),**[router flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) & navigator.

The back end i need to work with is **GraphQL**. What should i do now?

Can i integrate Relay to my app without affecting anything related to redux or should i dump redux and use relay?. What about [lokka](https://github.com/kadirahq/lokka)? Really confused!! Can someone help me with code examples or anything related to this issue?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: My thought is that you don't need graph data for everything...E.g  a messaging component - It'd make sense to use a REST api to get the initial messages and then use web sockets to get anything after that; Each message would get appended to the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use relay and redux in same application without much(I dont have any till today) issues(the App will be in production after few weeks). I could explain how I achieved it. (I am also new react-native and Js development, I don't claim this as the best approach, but at least it works for me as I intended)

Setting up of relay and graphQL almost took a day of effort. For this use following commands:-

```
npm install babel-core --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-react-native --save-dev
npm install babel-relay-plugin --save-dev
npm install react-relay --save
npm install graphql --save-dev
npm install sync-request --save-dev
```

then create a file named `babelRelayPlugin.js` and copy the below code.

```
const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin')
const introspectionQuery = require('graphql/utilities').introspectionQuery
const request = require('sync-request')

const url = 'your_api_here'

const response = request('POST', url, {
  qs: {
    query: introspectionQuery
  }
})

const schema = JSON.parse(response.body.toString('utf-8'))

module.exports = { plugins: [getBabelRelayPlugin(schema.data, { abortOnError: true })] }
```

and replace the code your .babelrc with this:-

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    "./scripts/babelRelayPlugin",
    "react-native"
  ]
}
```

following classes may need to use this import statement:-

```
import Relay, {
  Route,
  DefaultNetworkLayer
} from 'react-relay'
```

And my App.js file look like:-

```
  function configureStore(initialState){
      const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
        ),
        autoRehydrate()
      );

        return createStore(reducer,initialState,enhancer);
    }

    const store = configureStore({});
    persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage})
    ////relay network layer injecting
    Relay.injectNetworkLayer(new DefaultNetworkLayer('your_api'))
    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            {//here is your react-native-router-flux Navigation router}
            <NavigationRouter/>
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

After injecting relay network layer, you could use the following code in any containers to call from relay. Here is an example render method of one of my containers:-

```
render() {
    var value = 'some_value';
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Relay.RootContainer
        Component={TestComponent}
        //relay_route is imported from relay_route.js
        route={new relay_route({id:value})}
        renderFetched={(data)=> {
          return (
            <TestComponent parentProps={this.props} {...data} />
          );}}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

the relay_route.js should look something like

```
class relay_route extends Route {
  static paramDefinitions = {
    userID: { required: true }
  }
  static queries = {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      query { 
        user(id: $userID)
      }
    `
  }
  static routeName = 'UserRoute'
}
```

And My TestComponent looks like:-

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    const user = this.props.user
    return (
      <Text>name: {user.name}</Text>
    )
  }
}

export default TestComponent = Relay.createContainer(TestComponent, {
  fragments: {
      user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id,
        name
      }
    `
  }
})
```

For any doubts regarding relay, [this](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/getting-started.html#content) documentation is classy to help us